# Command line in OSX breaks when I edit bash_profile

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, terminal, .bash-profile

Please help me, I am learning how to add sublime to command line from [this link](http://blog.olivierlacan.com/posts/launch-sublime-text-2-from-the-command-line/)
and when I created `.bash_profile` file, in the first line I typed `export PATH=` and saved it.

My command line is broken. I can't do anything with command (for example, I can't use `ls`, `nano`, `mkdir`, `rm`, etc.) and when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to view all commands, I see

[image: img]
[image: img]

I tried `echo $PATH` but it returns " " (empty or null). Please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: Well, don't set `PATH` to an empty string. I don't see the linked blog post suggesting that you should do it.

Comment: oops! i misunderstand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
export PATH=
```

will set you PATH variable to blank and not enable the shell to find any commands.  You should delete this line from your .bash_profile and your problem will be fixed.

I just checked the link referenced in your post and I think this is the line your having a problem with:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:(...)
```

I think the author of the blog really meant to write this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

This will work correctly.  Try adding that line to your .bash_profile.  It will simply ensure that commands contained in /usr/local/bin are found first when the shell searches for them (which it does when you type 'rm' for example)

Comment: Oh! i error to reading hahaha//
i tried to open .bash_profile for editing but permission denied and i can't use sudo command. how i open bash_file and edit it without sudo command?

Thank

Comment: The same way you added the line in the first place!!

Comment: i used "sudo touch ~/.bash_profile" and "sudo nano ~/.bash_profile" but now i can't use both command. //sorry i newbie for command line

Comment: /usr/bin/sudo will get you the sudo command

Comment: O.o wowww it's excellent!! command is come back to me hahaha

Thank you so much!!

Comment: your welcome! you can check this off as being the correct answer please